# Короткий условный оператор работает не так как полный

Tags: javascript

Странная ситуация. Рассмотрим на примере. Допустим высчитаем чётное или нечётное число перед нами:

```
var time = new Date().getTime();

if ( time % 2 )
    console.log('Нечётное')
else
    console.log('Чётное')
```

Работает. Да... Но краткость - сестра таланта:

```
( time % 2 )
    ? console.log('Нечётное покороче')
    : console.log('Чётное покороче')
```

По идее обе записи аналогичны, но в результате короткой записи ловим "егорку":

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

**WTF?**

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmqyK/)**

Comment: У меня всё работает. Попробуйте после каждого выражения поставить точку с запятой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

я думаю, вам нужно расставить точки с запятыми, и ситуация изменится, [пруф.](http://jsfiddle.net/tmqyK/1/)

т.к. в данном случае код парсится следующим образом:

```
if ( time % 2 )
    console.log('Нечётное')
else
    console.log('Чётное')( time % 2 ) ...
```

т.к. `console.log` возвращает undefined, то вызвать оператор () у него не представляется возможным, отсюда и ошибка `undefined is not a function`

Comment: Ох чёрт. Насмотревшись на исходники твиттер бутстрапа я взял эту привычку не ставить точки с запятыми. Но у них то ошибок подобного плана не возникает... То есть точка с запятой нужна только в том случае когда возникает ситуация `()()`?

Comment: @Яковлев Андрей возьмите себе в привычку после каждого выражения ставить точку с запятой. Это предотвратит многие неявные ошибки да и код легче будет читаться.

Comment: неее..) теперь я осознаю когда она *действительно* нужна

Comment: @Яковлев Андрей если вы хотите сэкономить таким способом код, то я вас огорчу. Попробуйте "такой вод без точки с запятой" пропустить через компрессор. Всё равно силы добра победят и точки запятой будут стоять на своем месте.

Comment: >Насмотревшись на исходники твиттер бутстрапа я взял эту привычку не ставить точки с запятыми

когда будете делать проекты уровня твиттер бутстрапа, тогда можете брать эту привычку, а пока никакого evala, with и везде точки с запятыми!

Answer (score 2):

У меня работает такой вариант: http://jsfiddle.net/7Lyzv/

```
var time = new Date().getTime()
time % 2 ? console.log('Чётное покороче') : console.log('Нечётное покороче')
```

Comment: Вы не учли предыдущий код. 
>var time = new Date().getTime()
>(time % 2) ? console.log('Чётное покороче') : console.log('Нечётное покороче');

Так тоже не будет работать.

Comment: Так не будет, а как я написал будет. Вопрос ведь был как сделать кратко, чтобы не получать ошибку. Так вот, ошибка не возникает, если не использовать скобки в time%2.

Comment: @komka, вы мне дали ещё пищи для размышлений о синтаксисе JS

Answer (score 0):

Ребят, это всё описано очень подробно, как JS парсит код и расставляет за вас точки с запятой.
[bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/ru/#core.semicolon](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/ru/#core.semicolon)

[github.com/rwldrn/idiomatic.js/tree/master/translations/ru_RU](https://github.com/rwldrn/idiomatic.js/tree/master/translations/ru_RU)

Просвещайтесь и не ЛЕНИТЕСЬ ставить точки с запятой.